# Black wire between two switches

Tags: switch, light

I have a double switch ( see pic), where the switch on the left is a double pole that runs an outside light.  The switch on the right is a 3-way the controls lights inside my garage.  I attempted to replace the outside light switch (left) with a timer switch, but couldn't get it to work (the timer switch would display, but it wouldn't turn on the outside light).  So I then decided to try and go back to my original setup.  When I originally started this, I noticed that the switch on the right had a black wire going from it's common terminal to one of the hot terminals on the switch on the left.  The switch on the left had another black wire going to another of its terminal, coming from the wall.  The switch on the right had a white neutral going to it, while the switch on the left did not. When I attempted to put things back the way it was, the outside lights (left switch) seem to work, but the right switch no longer works.  Thoughts?  I ultimately would love to get the timer switch working, but even if I get back to the way it was, that would be helpful.  Thanks! [image]

Comment: Can you post photos of how the wires connect to the switches please? Something isn't making sense here

Comment: It looks like (picture) you now have two black connected to the switch on the right (is the black going up just a leader?). Please do not guess at what goes where, trial and error = fire/electrocution. By description it sounds like the switch on the right was using a switch loop (so the white was the switched hot - but don't guess at this, check), but you said it is a 3-way.  Do you have a picture of how it started? What else did the switch on the left control (you said double pole).

Comment: White at a switch wired before NEC 2011 is rarely, if ever, Neutral. White connected to a "dumb switch" is never neutral, unless several other code violations are going on.

Comment: NoybMan - the black wire you see coming out the top of the right switch is not connected to anything.  I disconnected while replacing the left switch, as that black cable was connected to a terminal on the left switch.

Comment: Sounds like you had a switch loop , I hope you have the original connections documented including at the timer. It did not work because you don’t understand switch wiring. Research switch loops, the white is supposed to be hot so it doesn’t get confused as a neutral. If you don’t have the original connections documented, this is going to take a while. So look at switch loops to understand and return everything to the working state original parts and we go from there much easier.

Comment: EdBeal - appreciate the response, although don’t appreciate the commentary.  Your right, I don’t under stand switch wiring which is why I am here obviously.  Everything is back the way it was from what I documented.  As I stated:  The left switch (double pole used as a single pole) has two black wires and ground going to it.  The right switch is a 3way that has a black wire and neutral.  Two neutrals are wire nutted.  Where I am getting confused is other the black wire that was connected between the two switches.  Either way, when I put it back the left switch works but the right does not

Comment: If there was a 3-way switch here, I'd expect at least one cable to have a red wire.   Are you *very sure* on your terminology (2-pole; 3-way)?  Not picking faults, but it's essential to describe things accurately. or else nothing will make sense.

Comment: Yep, it’s def a three way switch on the right and a double pole on the left.  No red cables

Comment: The folks trying to help are **very experienced** with house wiring. When they imply that it would be unusual to see a true double-pole switch used for lighting in this scenario, you should listen. I guarantee they can help with this mess if you provide clear pictures of both original switches and which clearly show each wire, then follow their directions.

Comment: "Double pole switch" is *not* a technical term for "switch with 2 screws on it". An actual "double pole switch" would have 4 terminals, but there's no reason that you would need one of those for your outside light.

Answer (score 2):

Note: This is a fair ways short of being a complete answer, for obvious reasons. I'll make it community wiki, or feel free to write a different answer if enough information comes forth to do that.

> "Everything is back the way it was from what I documented. As I
> stated: The left switch (double pole used as a single pole) has two
> black wires and ground going to it. The right switch is a 3way that
> has a black wire and neutral. Two neutrals are wire nutted. Where I am
> getting confused is other the black wire that was connected between
> the two switches. Either way, when I put it back the left switch works
> but the right does not"

No, it's not back the way it was. If it WAS, it would work as it did before.  As I stated in my comment above, White connected to a "dumb switch" is **never** Neutral. Get that straight, stop calling that wire a neutral, or you'll never get out of this mess.

It's a hot wire in a switch loop, or possibly a traveller in an odd version of wiring a 3-way. If you fix this right, that white wire will be marked with black (or red, or any color but green or grey) tape (or paint, or shrink tubing) when you are done.

If you did not carefully identify WHICH White wire and WHICH Black wire were connected to each location, you can't very well put them back the way they were.

Did you disconnect the two white wires that were wirenutted, or not? If not, the path to sorting it might be shorter - if so, you will need to sort out which white wire was not wirenutted.

In any case, you'll have to sort out which black wire went where. It's guaranteed that some or all of these wires are not, in fact, where they were when both of these switches worked, or both of these switches would work now.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give this a shot as well - In my first comment above (and everyone else's); we point out that what you are calling things, what we see in the single picture posted, and how lights work regardless of what you are calling them and the wires in the picture don't add up.

The simplest and safest advice for everyone and certainly yourself and anyone living in or near this home is to get an electrician in and they can trace the wires and solve the issue.  If you want to complete this project, it became much bigger the moment you lost the ability to 100% return the wiring to the way it was without guesswork. **Also be aware**; that if you are certain the wiring is back to the way it was and something is not working then its likely it got fried.

Here's a list of how you might safely start to troubleshoot:

1. Get an AC Detector, a multimeter, a wire toner, a notebook and pen
2. Turn off all power besides the main breaker, then verify nothing has power in the home (it shouldn't)!
3. Ensure no open wires you have are exposed or tied to anything (not even to the switches you removed), cap them off (all wires)
4. Turn only the single (1) one breaker on that you think is powering this circuit
5. Use the AC Detector and identify what white or black wires have a hot signal (if any, even if more than one, check white and black, treat these wires as if you are colorblind) - label any wires as HOT and the breaker # (let us know too when you post back)
6. Turn off that single breaker, and turn on the rest... then repeat #5.  This is confirming you have only one circuit in this box (which you probably do based on the picture)
7. Turn off the breakers again, and then using the meter, on Ohms/continuity, test the wires with one lead on the ground *(bare copper) and the other lead to each of the remaining unlabeled wires (remove a cap then replace it when done) - you should get **AT LEAST ONE** (and presumably only one that gives you near 0 ohms/beep), it should only be white, but regardless, label it as the return. If you get more than one let us know!

After doing the above, you should find you have ONE romex with a black labeled HOT and a white labeled RETURN/NEUTRAL.  This is just so we know where to start, and if there is more than one circuit in the box. There is still more to do.

The other two 14/2 romex wires certainly go to your lights (one for outside one for inside?). *Since you don't have enough wire for a 3 way setup unless someone did something insane one of these is probably part of a switch loop* (because you told us a white was connected to the right switch). The thing is, the count of wires in the box and what you tell us this is was doing + how you explained it was hooked up does not quite add up.

once you've done the above, you can use the toner, **(with the breakers off)** to tone out the other two romex wires at least to the first bulb(s) in the series, remove the bulb, and check the socket for the tone. We might need you to pull the socket to confirm how it is wired inside but we can get to that in part 2.